# CKEditor strips anchor tags between li tags

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor version 4.5.11 and there is a problem with removing anchor tags. The following is how the code should look like:

```
<ul class="social foo">
     <li><a href="https://telegram.me" title="test" target="_blank" class="icon-paper-plane"></a></li>                        
     <li><a href="https://instagram.com" title="test" target="_blank" class="icon-instagram"></a></li>
</ul>
```

and this is how does it look like after saving and reloading the page:

```
<ul class="social foo">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

This is my `config.js` file's contents:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.language = 'fa';
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
    config.tabSpaces = 4;
    config.basicEntities = false;
    config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true
};
```

Comment: Have not tried the code but what happens if there is some text inside the <a ...></a> tags.

Comment: No, I haven't tried it

Comment: I think that might be the case due to empty anchor tag.

Comment: These tags have to be empty. Is there a way to avoid removing empty tags?!

Comment: &nbsp; ? Kind of an ugly solution but it worked in my scenario